# New to OOP, trying to pull the results of a method and display data from database. Getting 500 Error

Tags: php, oop, try-catch

I'm using the below method in a class and calling that method expecting a formatted address. The code is resulting in a 500 Error.

If I remove the `try/catch` block of code, it executes fine(but without the data from the DB), and if I put the try/catch block in my other page and use `var_dump($result)` it shows the associative array from the database.

Method:

```
public function shippingAddress($user_id){

    try{
        $results = $db->prepare("SELECT address, address2, city, state, postal_code, country FROM addresses WHERE kf_user = ?");
        $results->bindParam(1, $user_id);
        $results->execute();
        $result = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Query failed, could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }

    $this->street = $result['address'];
    $this->street2 = $result['address2'];
    $this->city = $result['city'];
    $this->state = $result['state'];
    $this->postal = $result['postal_code'];
    if(!empty($result['country'])):
        $this->country = $result['country'];
    endif;

    //compile variables into formatted address
    //street address        if address2 not set, don't include it.
    $output = $this->street . "<br/>";
    if(!empty($this->street2)) : 
        $output .= $this->street2 . "<br/>";
    endif;
    //city, state postal code
    $output .= $this->city . ", " . $this->state . " " . $this->postal . "<br/>";
    //country
    $output .= $this->country;

    //result
    return $output;
}
```

Other page:

```
<?php
    include_once ('inc/class.address.inc');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Address:</h1>
<?php 
    $address = new Address;
?>
  <address><?php echo $address->shippingAddress(1); ?></address>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Users/Jacques/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app-5_4_9/apache2/htdocs/LowBidMe/inc/class.address.inc on line 19

Comment: What does the log say? Have you set the respective ini settings to get as many debug messages as possible?

Comment: how do you initialize the variable $db? looks like in one case it is not properly set. on quick hack would be to use a function rather than a variable. like get_dbconn() and then just make sure this function is in an included file.

Comment: `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=". DB_HOST .";dbname=". DB_NAME .";port=". DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS);` It works in another file.

Comment: but where do you initialize it? please provide a complete example that reproduces the issue rather than chunks.

Comment: That is where it's initialized. What are you asking for? Also, what I posted IS everything aside from where I set the $db variable, which I just posted in the comments above.

Comment: Where do you get$db? you have invalid $db object

Comment: I moved the $db initialization out of the include file and into the method and it works, but I want to have it in the include. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have yet to declare the $db variable in the current scope. Therefore it is not 'initialised'.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Either initialise the DB variable before you query the database. like so.

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=". DB_HOST .";dbname=". DB_NAME .";port=". DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
try{
    $results = $db->prepare("SELECT address, address2, city, state, postal_code, country FROM addresses WHERE kf_user = ?");
    $results->bindParam(1, $user_id);
```

Or preferably, initalise the db in its own method like so:

```
private function setupDb(){
   $this->db = $db = new PDO("mysql:host=". DB_HOST .";dbname=". DB_NAME .";port=". DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
```

Then in your methods you can call the DB like so:

```
$this->db->prepare(QUERY);
```

Comment: I moved the $db initialization out of the include file and into the method and it works, but I want to have it in the include. Any tips?

Comment: You'll need to read more about scope, and how to access different variables from different places. Ideally, you would have one database object, and pass that into your classes that need to access it. Read up on dependency injection.

Comment: Even if I put the include inside the method I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

In `conn.php`

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
   $user = 'dbuser';
   $password = 'dbpass';

 try {
   $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit();
   }
```

in other pages:

```
public function shippingAddress($user_id){

    include('conn.php');

    try{
        $results = $db->prepare("SELECT address, address2, city, state, postal_code, country FROM addresses WHERE kf_user = ?");
        $results->bindParam(1, $user_id);
        $results->execute();
        $result = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Query failed, could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }

    $this->street = $result['address'];
    $this->street2 = $result['address2'];
    $this->city = $result['city'];
    $this->state = $result['state'];
    $this->postal = $result['postal_code'];
    if(!empty($result['country'])):
        $this->country = $result['country'];
    endif;

    //compile variables into formatted address
    //street address        if address2 not set, don't include it.
    $output = $this->street . "<br/>";
    if(!empty($this->street2)) : 
        $output .= $this->street2 . "<br/>";
    endif;
    //city, state postal code
    $output .= $this->city . ", " . $this->state . " " . $this->postal . "<br/>";
    //country
    $output .= $this->country;

    //result
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: How do I put the DB initialization in an include?

Comment: It did not work. I appreciate it though. Probably me being stupid. Thanks.